# laravel request array empties when all required validation fields are satisfied ,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When one of my required fields criteria is not met It all works just fine and as it should it gives me an error about filling up that required filed but as I satisfy all of the required validation fields the request array becomes empty , and Laravel raises all required errors .
PS : I did create a Request class to handle the requests but that didn't solve the problem.

Form:

```
@extends('frontend.myAccount.master')

 @section('myAccountPageContent')

<div class="page-content-on-my-account-page">
    <h1 class="text-center title-of-my-account text-rose">ثبت آگهی</h1>
    @if(count($errors) > 0 )
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
            کاربر گرامی خطاهای موجود را اصلاح نموده و مجددا اطلاعات را ارسال کنید.
        </div>
    @endif
    <form action="{{ route('insertAds') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i
                                    class="material-icons text-rose">work</i><span> اطلاعات شغلی</span></h3>
                        <div class="panel-border-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>
                            <select name="guild" title="انتخاب صنف" class="form-control"
                                    id="select-guild-in-add-new-ad">
                                <option disabled selected>انتخاب صنف</option>
                                @foreach($guilds as $guild)
                                    <option
                                            value="{{ $guild->id }}"
                                            @if(old('guild') == $guild->id)
                                            selected
                                            @endif>{{ $guild->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('guild'))
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    @foreach($errors->get('guild') as $msg)
                                        <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif
                            <select name="job" disabled title="انتخاب شغل" class="form-control"
                                    id="select-job-in-add-new-ad">
                                <option disabled selected>انتخاب شغل</option>
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('job'))
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    @foreach($errors->get('job') as $msg)
                                        <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row card-view-wrapper">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i
                                    class="material-icons text-rose">local_post_office</i><span>آدرس</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="panel-border-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>
                            <select name="province" title="انتخاب استان" class="form-control"
                                    id="select-province-in-add-new-ad">
                                <option disabled selected>انتخاب استان</option>
                                @foreach($provinces as $prv)
                                    <option value="{{ $prv->id }}"
                                            @if(old('province') == $prv->id)
                                            selected
                                            @endif>{{ $prv->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('province'))
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    @foreach($errors->get('province') as $msg)
                                        <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif
                            <select name="city" disabled title="انتخاب شهر" class="form-control"
                                    id="select-city-in-add-new-ad">
                                <option disabled selected>انتخاب شهر</option>
                            </select>
                            @if($errors->has('city'))
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    @foreach($errors->get('city') as $msg)
                                        <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="address-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">آدرس پستی</label>
                                <textarea name="postal_address" id="address-in-add-new-ad" class="form-control"
                                          cols="30"
                                          rows="2">{{ old('postal_address') }}</textarea>
                                @if($errors->has('postal_address'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('postal_address') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i
                                    class="material-icons text-rose">perm_contact_calendar</i><span>اطلاعات تماس</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="panel-border-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="phone-1-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">تلفن تماس 1</label>
                                <input type="text" value="{{ old('tel1') }}" name="tel1" id="phone-1-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('tel1'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('tel1') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="phone-2-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">تلفن تماس 2</label>
                                <input type="text" value="{{ old('tel2') }}" name="tel2" id="phone-2-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('tel2'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('tel2') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="phone-3-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">تلفن تماس 3</label>
                                <input type="text" name="tel3" value="{{ old('tel3') }}" id="phone-3-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('tel3'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('tel3') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="instagram-address-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">آدرس
                                    اینستاگرام</label>
                                <input type="text" name="instagram" value="{{ old('instagram') }}"
                                       id="instagram-address-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('instagram'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('instagram') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="telegram-address-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">آدرس
                                    تلگرام</label>
                                <input type="text" name="telegram" value="{{ old('telegram') }}"
                                       id="telegram-address-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('telegram'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('telegram') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="website-address-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">آدرس وب
                                    سایت</label>
                                <input name="website_url" value="{{ old('website_url') }}" type="text"
                                       id="website-address-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('website_url'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('website_url') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row card-view-wrapper">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="material-icons text-rose">bookmark</i><span>اطلاعات پایه آگهی</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="panel-border-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div style="min-height:900px;">
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="full-name-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">نام صاحب
                                    آگهی</label>
                                <input name="full_name" value="{{ old('full_name') }}" type="text"
                                       id="full-name-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('full_name'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('full_name') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="full-name-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">عنوان
                                    آگهی</label>
                                <input name="titleeee" value="{{ old('title') }}" type="text"
                                       id="full-name-in-add-new-ad" class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('title'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('title') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="facilities-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">خدمات و
                                    امکانات</label>
                                <input name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" type="text"
                                       id="facilities-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('description'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('description') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group label-floating custom-form-group">
                                <label for="working-time-in-add-new-ad" class="control-label">ساعت
                                    کاری</label>
                                <input name="working_time" value="{{ old('working_time') }}" type="text"
                                       id="working-time-in-add-new-ad"
                                       class="form-control">
                                @if($errors->has('working_time'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('working_time') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default custom-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i
                                    class="material-icons text-rose">attach_file</i><span>ضمیمه ها</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="panel-border-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail img-raised">
                                    <img src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::to('/frontend/img') }}/notavailable.jpg"
                                         alt="...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail img-raised"></div>
                                <div>
                                <span class="btn btn-raised btn-round btn-success btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileinput-new">انتخاب تصویر کاور</span>
                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">تغییر عکس</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="cover_photo"/>
                                </span>
                                    <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists"
                                       data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> حذف</a>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('cover_photo'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('cover_photo') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group form-file-upload">
                                <label for="upload-video-clip-in-add-new">آپلود ویدئو کلیپ(مخصوص اپلیکیشن موبایل با
                                    فرمت 3gp):</label>
                                <input type="file" name="video_clip" id="upload-video-clip-in-add-new">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-s">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-rose">
                                        <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('video_clip'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('video_clip') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-file-upload">
                                <label for="upload-video-clip-mp4-in-add-new">آپلود ویدئو کلیپ(مخصوص وب سایت با فرمت
                                    mp4):</label>
                                <input type="file" name="video_clip_mp4" id="upload-video-clip-mp4-in-add-new">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-s">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-rose">
                                        <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('video_clip_mp4'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('video_clip_mp4') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="form-group form-file-upload">
                                <label for="upload-amr-audio-clip-in-add-new">آپلود فایل صوتی(مخصوص اپلیکیشن
                                    موبایل با فرمت amr):</label>
                                <input type="file" name="voice_file_name" id="upload-amr-audio-clip-in-add-new">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-s">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-rose">
                                        <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('voice_file_name'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('voice_file_name') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-file-upload">
                                <label for="upload-audio-mep-clip-in-add-new">آپلود فایل صوتی(مخصوص پخش در
                                    وب با فرمت mp3):</label>
                                <input type="file" name="voice_file_name_mp3" id="upload-audio-mep-clip-in-add-new">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-s">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-rose">
                                        <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('voice_file_name_mp3'))
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        @foreach($errors->get('voice_file_name_mp3') as $msg)
                                            <li><span class="text-danger inline-error">{{ $msg }}</span></li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rose btn-round">تایید</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/ads/create', 'AdsUpdateHistoryController@add')->name('insertAds');
Route::get('/ads/create', 'AdsController@showCreatePage')->name('createAdShow');
```

Controller:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'guild' => 'required|numeric|exists:guild,id',
        'job' => 'required|numeric|exists:job,id',
        'province' => 'required|numeric|exists:province,id',
        'city' => 'required|numeric|exists:city,id',
        'postal_address' => 'nullable',
        'latitude' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'longitude' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'tel1' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'tel2' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'tel3' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'instagram' => 'string|nullable|max:300',
        'telegram' => 'string|nullable|max:300',
        'website_url' => 'string|nullable',
        'full_name' => 'nullable|string|max:200',
        'titleeee' => 'required|string|max:200',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
        'working_time' => 'nullable|string',
        'cover_photo' => 'image|nullable',
        'video_clip' => 'file|mimes:3gp|nullable',
        'video_clip_mp4' => 'file|mimes:mp4|nullable',
        'voice_file_name' => 'file|mimes:amr|nullable',
        'voice_file_name_mp3' => 'file|mimes:mp3|nullable',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors()->all();
        $inputs = $request->all();

        return [
            'errors' => $errors,
            'request' => $inputs
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in your view? Because that's not where the validation must happen, this should be in either your model or controller.

Comment: Where are you attempting to use the `$request` past validation? Please provide that code.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array, where you want an Instance of `Response` (for example `view()`, `redirect()`, `back()`, etc. ).

Check the last part to see the changes:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'guild' => 'required|numeric|exists:guild,id',
        'job' => 'required|numeric|exists:job,id',
        'province' => 'required|numeric|exists:province,id',
        'city' => 'required|numeric|exists:city,id',
        'postal_address' => 'nullable',
        'latitude' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'longitude' => 'numeric|nullable',
        'tel1' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'tel2' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'tel3' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'instagram' => 'string|nullable|max:300',
        'telegram' => 'string|nullable|max:300',
        'website_url' => 'string|nullable',
        'full_name' => 'nullable|string|max:200',
        'titleeee' => 'required|string|max:200',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
        'working_time' => 'nullable|string',
        'cover_photo' => 'image|nullable',
        'video_clip' => 'file|mimes:3gp|nullable',
        'video_clip_mp4' => 'file|mimes:mp4|nullable',
        'voice_file_name' => 'file|mimes:amr|nullable',
        'voice_file_name_mp3' => 'file|mimes:mp3|nullable',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors()->all();
        $inputs = $request->all();

        return back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }

    // Validator succeeded, do saving stuff etc.
}
```